# NextJs Fails in production v13.4.12 using AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, axios, frontend, aws-amplify, next.js13

I have made a frontend in NextJs 13 to current date using (App directory) but when I deploy it in AWS Amplify, sometimes I get "500|Internal Server Error" on pages that have already rendered, or an error like "Application error: a server-side exception has occurred", it doesn't happen frequently.

I am using Axios to connect to an external api in AWS Lambda from NextJs.

- I have already tested setting the environment variables in amplify.
- I have changed some text rendering things since I use i18n for multi-language.
- I have placed try-cath and in functions that are going to make connections with axios.

The solutions I found on the internet didn't work for me and those errors can't even be replicated in local environment.

The only thing I have seen in the Cloudwatch logs is:
1 - This is when it says "Application error: ...": * Error: Cannot access .propTypes on the server. You cannot dot into a client module from a server component. You can only pass the imported name through.
2 - This is when it says "500|Inter...":* Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './server.edge' is not defined by "exports" in /var/task/node_modules/react-dom/package.json

What can I do?

I have also used

```
    export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

```
    import dynamicComponent from "next/dynamic";
    const anyname = dynamicComponent(
       () => import("@/components/anycomponent"),
       {
         loading: () => <>Loading...< />,
       }
    );
```

I have done this even for different pages but the two errors mentioned above persist.

Comment: Are you using server components or client components for Next.js?

Comment: If you're using serverside components via pages/api, you'll need to add your environment variables to your buildspec on the aws amplify console.

Comment: @Luke i am having the same issue and i have added my environment variables to the buildspec on the aws amplify console so i don't think is the issue.

In my case, it works sometimes and sometimes it breaks. I always deploy the project on vercel just to test and everything works fine. So i really believe it has somethin to do with AWS

Comment: @eaaldark, have you been able to solve this issue ????

Comment: Same issue for me as well on Amplify with next 13.4.12. @eaaldark, any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

i found this on Amplify docs :

> Amplify doesn't currently support On-Demand ISR. If your app is using
> Next.js on-demand revalidation, this feature won't work when you
> deploy your app to Amplify.

From my tests. Amplify does not allow to the cache revalidation. i get this error :
"Failed to update prerender cache for /index [Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/tmp/app/.next/server/app/index.html']"

Meanwhile on vercel it should be working fine. (didn't try it yet)

i hope AWS will fix that quick.

here is the link (look for the section "On-Demand Incremental Static Regeneration isn't working for your app") : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html